# Firefox: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch (How to delay form submit until javascript is executed?)

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, pdfmake

I have this solution integrated (a simplified example is below)

```
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="downloadPdf()" >
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
  <label><input name="privacy" type="checkbox" required> I agree to the privacy policy</label><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<script src='build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function downloadPdf() {

          // create PDF
            pdfMake.fonts = {
                // my fonts here
            },
           let docDefinition = {
                // my definitions here
            };
       pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
        }
</script>
```

So, form submitting does two things, executes PDFMake and submits the form.
It works in Chrome and Edge without issues, but in Firefox I am getting this error

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch (url: "http://localhost/site/assets/fonts/myfont.woff")`

Do you maybe have idea how to solve this?

What's funny, when I remove the privacy checkbox from the form it also works in Firefox.
But the privacy checkbox is mandatory these days, so I can't remove it.

**I think form submiting should be delayed until javascript function downloadPdf() is executed and then submit the form. Which works automaticaly in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox.**
But I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Not clear how that privacy checkbox should have anything to do with the PDF creation, and specifically accessing the font files. Sounds to me as if your analysis is most likely not correct to begin with there (unless there is any other client-side JS functionality tied to that checkbox as well?), and it was rather pure coincidence.